# Fazer uma pesquisa Dentro de um Listview personalizado com o firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, listview, firebase-database

Basicamente o meu projeto se assemelha a uma rede social, usando o firebase realtime database, porem de deparei com um problema, eu criei uma listView personalizada e minha ideia era... Como eu tinha 2 childs >Usuarios e >Posts, na Child post tem um nó do email do usuario, ou seja dentro da listView eu capturaria o nome do usuario/avatar (usando o campo/no email que tinha no child post) ... porem o que aconteceu foi que.. nao funcionou, ja tentei varias coisas porem nada deu certo, se alguem poder me ajudar... ficaria EXTREMAMENTE feliz

(nesse caso eu simplesmente tentei pegar o nome do usuario.. oque acontece é so carrega o nome de um usuario, ou apenas o ultimo da listview)

**EDIT.. APOS ALGUNS TESTES EU NOTEI QUE, O MEU CODIGO APENAS ATUALIZA O ULTIMO ITEM DA LISTVIEW, POREM COM O VALOR QUE DEVERIA IR PARA O PRIMEIRO ITEM?? NAO FAZ SENTIDO PRA MIM**

> segue os códigos

1.Tela que chama o ListView

```
package com.gabriel.arhur.team.kindness02project;


public class TelaInicial extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton floatButton;

    ListView listV_dados;
    private List<Post> listPost = new ArrayList<Post>();
    private PostTI_ListAdapter arrayAdapterPost;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Post postSelect = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_inicial);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tela Inicial");
        floatButton = findViewById(R.id.floatboton);
        listV_dados = findViewById(R.id.List_posts);
        iniciaFirebase();
        eventoFirebase();
        eventoonclick();


        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN
        );
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        eventoFirebase();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(mSwipeRefreshLayout, "Recarregado", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                        snackbar.show();
                    }

                },3000);
            }
        });
    }


    private void iniciaFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(TelaInicial.this);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }

    private void eventoFirebase() {
        databaseReference.child("Post").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listPost.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post p = objSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    listPost.add(p);

                }

                arrayAdapterPost = new PostTI_ListAdapter(TelaInicial.this, R.layout.activity_post_ti__list_adapter, listPost);
                listV_dados.setAdapter(arrayAdapterPost);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void eventoonclick() {
        floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(TelaInicial.this, NovosPosts.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        listV_dados.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                postSelect = (Post) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                alert(postSelect.getUid());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_pesquisa) {
            alert("pesquisa");
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_Perfil) {
            alert("perfil");
            Intent i = new Intent(TelaInicial.this, PerfilUser.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void alert(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(TelaInicial.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

2.Codigo do ListView

```
public class PostTI_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    private Activity context;
    private int resource;
    private List<Post> list;


    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    TextView textDescricao,textTitulopost,textLocalização,textnomeperfil;
    ImageView  PostImage;
    String nome;

    public PostTI_ListAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Post> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        list = objects;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        textDescricao= v.findViewById(R.id.textDescrição);
        textTitulopost = v.findViewById(R.id.textTitulo);
        textLocalização = v.findViewById(R.id.textlocal);
        PostImage = v.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);
        textnomeperfil = v.findViewById(R.id.textnomeperfil);


        textDescricao.setText(list.get(position).getDescricao_post());
        textTitulopost.setText(list.get(position).getTitulo());
        Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getUrl_image()).into(PostImage);
        textLocalização.setText(((list.get(position).getEstado()))+"-"+((list.get(position).getCidade())));


//Pesquisa... porem nao deu certo

        String email= list.get(position).getCriador();
notifyDataSetChanged();
        DatabaseReference raiz = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query =raiz.child("Usuario").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    textnomeperfil.setText(objSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString());



                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });





        return v;
    }

}
```

3. segue o banco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja na estrutura do seu banco, adicione na pergunta um json de exemplo de dados

Comment: atualizei com um Screenshot do banco, e uma informação na "introdução" da postagem